# Docker Swarm Linking

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I want to create a Docker Swarm Cluster running an elastic search instance, a MongoDB instance and a grails app, each on a separate machine. I'm using Docker Machine to set up my Docker Swarm Cluster

> swarm-01:
>     mongodb
>     mongodb_ambassador
>
> swarm-02:
>     elasticsearch
>     elasticsearch_ambassador
>
> swarm-03:
>     mongodb_ambassador
>     elasticsearch_ambassador
>     grails

The last step of my setup, running the actual grails app, using the following command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d --name grails-master --volumes-from maven --link mongo:mongo-master --link es:es-master my-grails-image
```

fails with error:

> Error response from daemon: Unable to find a node fulfilling all
>   dependencies: --volumes-from=maven --link=mongo:mongo-master
>   --link=es:es-master

The ambassador containers and the maven data container are all running on the same node.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                          NAMES
74677dad09a7        svendowideit/ambassador   "/bin/sh -c 'env | gr"   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                                             swarm-03/es
98b38c4fc575        svendowideit/ambassador   "/bin/sh -c 'env | gr"   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       27107/tcp                                                      swarm-03/mongo
7d45fb82eacc        debian:jessie             "/bin/bash"              20 minutes ago                                                                                         swarm-03/maven
```

I'm not able to get the Grails app running on the Swarm cluster; any advice would be appreciated. Running all containers on a single machine works, so I guess I'm making a mistake linking the mongo and es instances to the grails app.

Btw I'm using latest Docker Toolbox installation on OS X.

Comment: look for the crashed grails app container with `docker ps -a`, then check its logs `docker logs grails_app_container_id`.

Comment: One year later, is this question still unsolved ?

Answer (score 2):

"linking" is deprecated in docker. Don't use it. It's complicated and not flexible enough.
Just create an overlay network for swarm mode.

`docker network create -d overlay mynetwork`

In swarm mode (even in single container mode), just add every service who should communicate with another service to the same network.

`docker service create --network mynetwork --name mymongodb ...`

Other services in the same network can reach your mongodb service just over the hostname `mymongodb`. That's all. Docker swarm mode has battery included.